# Exception : java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Using Spring Boot 2.1.0, we are getting the following stack trace on one of our servers. This is not happening on the other servers though. We are using the same baseline for all of the servers.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:548)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getOutputStream(ResponseFacade.java:210)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getOutputStream(ServletResponseWrapper.java:100)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse.getOutputStream(ErrorPageFilter.java:381)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getOutputStream(ServletResponseWrapper.java:100)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getOutputStream(ServletResponseWrapper.java:100)
        at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.getOutputStream(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:139)
        at com.mycompany.rest.controller.ReferralController.viewUploadedDocument(ReferralController.java:160)
        at com.mycompany.rest.controller.ReferralController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ff8620dc.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
--
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at com.mycompany.rest.security.JwtTokenFilter.doFilter(JwtTokenFilter.java:52)
```

The controller method. As far as I can tell the Writer/OutputStream is only retrieved once.

```
    @GetMapping("/document/{documentId}")
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Blah") })
    public void viewUploadedDocument(@PathVariable("documentId") final Long documentId,
            final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        final MyDocument result = myService.getResult(documentId);

        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + result.getFileName() + "\"");

        final byte[] content = result.getContent();
        if (content == null) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "Not found");
        } else {
            response.setContentLength(content.length);
            final OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            os.write(content, 0, content.length);
            os.close();
        }
    }
```

For some reason, getWriter has already been called but the error condition should not be called if there is content.

Could the Swagger @ApiResponses annotation cause this?

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thank You.

Comment: Look like you are getting error in below method, but you have given the sample of getDocument() method code. Please share the viewUploadedDocument method code.
 
com.ensocare.rest.controller.ReferralController.viewUploadedDocument(ReferralController.java:160)

Comment: ReferralController.viewUPloadedDocument is the same method that is shown. I renamed the method for posting but forgot about the stack trace. Edited and changed it back to the actual name shown in the stack.